# Dictionary searching getting time out… what to do

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;

class Solution{
    public static void main(String []argh){
        Map<String,String> phoneBook =new HashMap<String,String>();
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = in.nextInt();
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
            String name = in.next();
            String phone = in.next();
           phoneBook.put(name,phone);
           }
           System.out.println("now search");
        while(in.hasNext()){
            String s = in.next();
           for(Map.Entry<String,String> e : phoneBook.entrySet() )
         {
            e.getKey();
            if(name1==s)
            {
              System.out.println(e.getKey()+" : "+e.getValue());
            }
            else
            {
             System.out.println("Not found");
            }
         }
           }
        in.close();
    *

    }
}*
```

What I'm trying to do is enter some values in the dictionary, and then search if a particular string is there in the dictionary… it's working, but I'm getting terminated due to time out. Any better way to do it???

Comment: Why are you looping the entire `Map`, when a `get()` call can do a direct lookup by key? That *is* the purpose of the `Map`, you know. --- Also, what do you think `e.getKey()` does, when you don't use the return value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a hashmap so you shall use its feature instead of iterating keys one by one.

try :

```
 while(in.hasNext()){
                String s = in.next();

               String value = phonebook.get(s);
                if(value!=null)
                {
                  System.out.println(s+" : "+value);
                }
                else
                {
                 System.out.println("Not found");
                }
             }
```

Comment: Since phone book cannot have `null` values, don't do a double lookup with `contains()` + `get()`. Just do a `get()` and check for `null` return value.